# Last row in .xlsx file with xlrd nrows

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, loops, xlrd

I'm trying to cross information from a .xlsx file and a .json file.
However I'm getting issues to get to the last row of the .xlsx file...
The block of code that follows **if j ==** only would work if **j == 4823** which is strange because the end of the file, theoretically, is 10418... Somehow the code doesn't read the values of end rows has it should. Do you know how I could resolve this issue without the use of a constant for the condition?

The end of the .xlsx file looks like this:
[image]

Python code:

```
# DEFINE INPUT JSON FILE
at_file = open(glob('*.json')[0])
data = json.load(at_file)
# DEFINE INPUT XLSX FILE
s_file = xlrd.open_workbook(glob('BAU*.xlsx')[0])
s_file_sheet = s_file.sheet_by_index(0)
# GO THROUGH JSON FILE
print(s_file_sheet.nrows)  -------------------------------------------------->  output: 140418
for i in range(0, len(data['results'])):
    if 'windows' in data['results'][i]['variables']:
        # GO THROUGH XLSX FILE
        for j in range(s_file_sheet.nrows):
            if (s_file_sheet.cell_value(j, 78) == 'BANCO' and
                    s_file_sheet.cell_value(j, 113) == 'MICROSOFT'):
                if ((data['results'][i]['name']).replace(
                        '.banco', '').lower() ==
                        s_file_sheet.cell_value(j, 91).lower()):
                    break
                if j == s_file_sheet.nrows - 1:  
                    print((data['results'][i]['name']).replace( ------------->  output: None
                         '.banco', '').lower())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Use Pandas read_xlsx or it can Be More Easier if you can Convert the Excel file into CSV and use pandas read_csv and do you Operations and then write it to JSON .. Pandas is till the Best Package for Doing operations on Excel / CSV / TSV Files.. You can Even use Pythons CSV Module to do the Same..

Comment: Thank you for the reply, actually that's what I did :)) I was trying to understand the problem in programming, how does this happen?

Comment: Glad that it helped you.